# Update large table with constant read requests

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to update a largish table (100k rows) that has a constant stream of read requests from clients.

I need to go over every row of the table and check if the data is outdated. If the row is outdated then overwrite with new data otherwise ignore and go to next row.

I can think of 2 strategies right now.

1. Create a background process that goes through the table row-by-row (or batch of rows) with `UPDATE`-s. Doesn't lock the whole table but is slow.
2. Create a new table from fresh data. Lock the old table for a moment. Delete the old table. Rename the fresh table to old.

Essentially:

```
CREATE TABLE fresh;
LOCK TABLE old IN EXCLUSIVE MODE;
DROP TABLE old;
ALTER TABLE fresh RENAME TO old;
```

How should I go about this? Does the 2-nd strategy work and is it thread-safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second method is safe as long as the updating session is the only writer on the table.

I would say that it is the better method in that case. The advantages are in my opinion:

- It is easy to rollback the update in case of problems (just drop the table copy).
- Therefore, you don't have to spend thought on a restart scenario if the update was interrupted.
- No table bloat.

The drawback is that you might need more space temporarily.

Answer (score 1):

you can create a view to one table and use the view in sql queries. when you create a new table and populate a data, then you can just recreate the view with a new table in it.